# how to get the text of user input in alexa using python flask-ask

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

Whatever and whenever user speaks I want to pass it to my API and send API response to Alexa using python flask-ask.

I don't want to use AWS lambda. I want to know is it possible and if it does then how can I achieve it.

eg:

```
UserVoiceInput = anything that user says

def anyfunc():
    abc = MyApiUrl?message=UserVoiceInput
    return statement(abc["Response_Message"])
```

how can I achieve the above logic using python flask-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this with flask-ask

```
@ask.intent("IntentName")
def function(slotvalue):
    example = get_api_response(slotvalue)
    example_msg = 'the result is {}'.format(example)
    return statement(example_msg)
```

then define your function some thing like below.

```
def get_api_response(value):
    # Do your api call 
    return response
```